# 仲裁を　願います。

Tags: サポート, コメント

[excelシート関数のみでの　〜2百万以上の、1次元配列連番の　生成。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/75802/excel%e3%82%b7%e3%83%bc%e3%83%88%e9%96%a2%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ae%e3%81%bf%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae-2%e7%99%be%e4%b8%87%e4%bb%a5%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%ae-1%e6%ac%a1%e5%85%83%e9%85%8d%e5%88%97%e9%80%a3%e7%95%aa%e3%81%ae-%e7%94%9f%e6%88%90)
にて、

コメント欄で　htb氏に、
以下のような　言動を、
浴びせられました。
"

其処で、

仲裁を　お願いします。
"

〉コードの修飾すら受け入れられない

機能しない　ものへとの、
プログラム改変でした。
"

あからさまに、

構文が　読めていない、
ものの、

意味を　全く、
他に　変える、
不適切な　表示へ、

への　改変でした。
"

故、

此は　違反改変でした。
"

例え、

其れが　文字修飾意図だろうと、
表示内容が　変わって、
意味改変へと　至っていたならば、

ロールバックは　止むないと、
思います。
"

Comment: 誹謗中傷云々についての部分は、メタで討議する内容ではないため削除編集をいたしました。この部分についてはヘルプページ「[迷惑行為を受けた場合、どうすればよい？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/harassment)」に従ってくださいますでしょうか。

Comment: にしても、意味が　変わる、改変ですよね？ロールバックさせて　頂きました。

Comment: 意味が改変されたとおっしゃる根拠を教えていただきますか？今のままだと、ただ改変が「された」「されてない」の水掛け論で論理的な討論には見えません。

Comment: 「主観性が高い」としてクローズに投票します。 keitaro_soさんもコメントされていますが、根拠を提示することなく一方的な主張が繰り返され続けています。

Answer (score 13):

Markdown によるコードの装飾や文章の投稿に関して認識違いがあるようです。

そもそもエクセルの関数を貼ったところでこのサイト上では動きません。ですので該当の編集も「機能しないプログラムへの改変」には当たりません。

「コードブロックのハイライト」は「プログラムがどこからどこまでか」を明確にするためのもので、nouble さんが段落の前後の行に (独自ルールで) `"` を挟んでいるのと大差ありません。
(コードブロックのハイライトは Markdown で定義された標準的なフォーマットです)

恐らく、非常に長い行が途中で切れたように見えているため、これを指して "改変" と言っているのかもしれませんが、プログラムは改行位置も重要になるため画面に収まらない場合は「上下左右にスクロール」できるように表示されます。

**iPhone 6/7/8 Plus 相当の表示:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**横にスクロール (スワイプ) 後:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

一方でただのテキスト (本文) は表示される画面のサイズに合わせてブラウザが適切に文章を折り返します。試しに手元の iPhone で自動回転を有効にしていくつかの web ページを表示してみるとよいでしょう。

nouble さんは iPhone の画面に合わせて「1行は20文字程度」という独自ルールで文章を構成していますが、例えばガラケーは1行が10文字程度なので以下のように表示が崩れます。

**1行が20文字程度の場合:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**1行が10文字程度の場合:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

iPhone だけを例にとっても様々な画面サイズがありますし、例え同じ端末でもユーザーが文字サイズを変更している場合だってあるので、**特定の画面サイズだけに依存するような書き方は避けるべきです**。

同様に、「コメント欄では改行が反映されませんよ」と仕様を伝えた以降も、段落を `"` で区切る書き方を続けられていますよね。こちらも (通常の使い方である) 引用符と区別がつかなくなるため、複数のユーザーが指摘しているような **読み辛さ** につながっています。

---

スタックオーバーフローで他人の投稿が編集できるのはあくまでナレッジとしての質を高めるためであり、一定のルールに沿っていることが求められます。万一意味を壊すような編集をしている人がいればペナルティを与えられる場合もありますが、nouble さんの投稿に対するコミュニティユーザーの編集に "悪さ" をしているものは見当たりません。

「他人の投稿を編集できる」サイトというのは確かにちょっと変わっているので、「句読点や空白文字の一つ一つにも意味が込められている」「他人からは干渉して欲しくない」ということであれば、別のQ&Aサイトを利用することも検討してください。
(サイトの規約に同意できないなら利用すべきではない)

Answer (score 9):

特に問題が無く、ロールバックの必要は無いと感じます。ソースコードを Markdown のブロックコード記法で装飾することは、表示上特定の HTML タグで囲われて装飾がなされるだけで、表示されるテキストには何の変更も加わりません。したがって元々機能していたプログラムであれば、そのまま機能するプログラムになります。（レアケースとしてプログラム中に ```` ``` ```` などが含まれていて装飾に失敗した場合は考えられますが、それは今回起こっていません。）

Comment: いいえ、
"
表示上では、
全く　機能しない、
ものへと、
変えられて　いましたので、
申される　限りでは、
ありません。

Comment: 具体的にどういう状況をもって「機能しない」と判断なさいましたか？

Comment: 1000000が　1に、変えられていましたよ。

Comment: 因みに、誹謗の　仲裁に付いて以外の、ご意見はお、断りさせて　頂きます。等スレッド　本意外です。

Comment: [編集履歴](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/75802/revisions)を見ても、表示されるテキスト自体は変化しておりません。`1000000` というコードが `1` に変えられたりもしていません。ご確認ください。

Comment: 私の回答に追記しましたが、特定の画面サイズでは一時的に途切れたように見えるものの、横にスクロールすればすべての情報は表示されます。